# How to avoid undefined index warning for chains of 'default' values?

Tags: php

Let's say I want to check for a couple of different parameters, and then fall back to a default value, is there a way to do it without ugly and verbose writing of `isset()`?

For example in JS we can do:

`var someVariable = otherVar || anotherVar || 'fallback here';`

The equivalent in PHP would be something like:

`$someVariable = (isset($otherVar) ? $otherVar : (isset($anotherVar) ? $anotherVar : 'fallback here'));`

which is obviously a mess and horrible to read.

Lots of solutions exist for single fallbacks, i.e.:

`$someVariable = $otherVar ?: 'fallback here';`

but that doesn't help me with requiring more than one in the line of checks.

Given that I am only interested in whether or not the value is set or truth-y (i.e. I am happy for 1 to be accepted as the used value, and for 0/false/null to be skipped and for the next parameter in the chain to be used), what is the best way to avoid the undefined index warning?

In reality, I would be doing this on arrays in *most* cases, but not all, and it's probably that they will be different arrays. I may want to use $_POST for the first, then check $_GET under a different key, and then fall back to a default string for example.

Comment: i used to do error_reporting(0); for the warning to go away..

Comment: I use error_reporting to check for other issues, so I don't want to turn that off.

Comment: I'd also prefer not to suppress E_NOTICE because I want to fundamentally solve the problem if possible rather than just mute it's report.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring PHP warnings and notices is not a good idea at all. 
But just for the experiment, I can suggest you the error control operator `@`. 
PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

```
$someVariable = @$otherVar ? @$var : 'fallback here';
echo $someVariable;
// output: fallback here
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: I didn't know that the @ operator could be used prior to the use of a variable; that's really interesting and might be a good solution for this..

Comment: I found that this doesn't help in the case of an array - so for example:

`$animals = array();
$my_animal = @$animals['dog'] ? $animals['dog'] : 'Some dog name';`

This still throws an undefined index warning for me - is there any way around that which you know of?

The alternative is so much more verbose, I really don't like it and it would take a month of Sundays' to retrofit it into my code!:

`if(isset($animals) && isset($animals['dog'])) { $my_animal = $animals['dog']; } else { $my_animal = 'Some dog name'; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can chain `?:` but you'll still need to [suppress errors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) with `@`.

For example, the following will work similarly to your JavaScript example:

```
$foo = @$bar ?: @$baz ?: @$qux ?: "I give up";
```

It's the equivalent of multiple "single fallbacks":

```
$foo = (@$bar ?: (@$baz ?: (@$qux ?: "I give up")));
```

Be careful though, `?:` only checks for *truthyness*.  There are scenarios where `isset()` and truthyness [do not agree](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).  Additionally, `?:` fallback functionality was introduced in [PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

If you only care about nullness and have PHP 7 available, it introduced a [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: That's a good point; truthyness isn't quite going to work because it would reject an explicitly-provided boolean false value for example. I love how this is styled though as it's simple and clear so it's a shame that won't work!

Answer (score 0):

This is ambiguous and it is deprecated...

```
$something = $a ? $b : $c ?: $d;
```

So, you have 2 alternatives for grouping:

```
$something = $a ? $b : ($c ?: $d); // version 1
$something = ($a ? $b : $c) ?: $d; // version 2
```

Which one is correct? Let's test this...

```
$posibilities = [TRUE, FALSE, NULL, [], new stdClass()];
$v1_is_correct = TRUE;
$v2_is_correct = TRUE;

foreach ($posibilities as $a) {
  foreach ($posibilities as $b) {
    foreach ($posibilities as $c) {
      foreach ($posibilities as $d) {

        $original = (int)($a ? $b : $c ?: $d);
        $v1 = (int)($a ? $b : ($c ?: $d));
        $v2 = (int)(($a ? $b : $c) ?: $d);

        $v1_is_correct = $v1_is_correct && ($original === $v1);
        $v2_is_correct = $v2_is_correct && ($original === $v2);

        print "ORIG: $original - V1: $v1 - V2: $v2 \n";
      }
    }
  }
}

print "\n";
$v1_is_correct ? print "V1 is correct \n" : NULL;
$v2_is_correct ? print "V2 is correct \n" : NULL;
```

**Result:** V2 is correct.

```
$a ? $b : $c ?: $d
```

is equivalent to...

```
($a ? $b : $c) ?: $d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to replace `isset` and ternaries, you can use the null coalescing operator `??`, which was [added in PHP 7.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php):

```php
$null = null;
$array = [];

$value = $null ?? null ?? $array[0] ?? $nonexistent ?? 'default';

echo $value; // Output: "default"
```

Like `isset`, this checks only if the value is null (or the variable/key doesn't exist), so falsy values may be returned:

```php
$blank = '';
$zero = 0;
$false = false;

echo 'Blank: ' . ($blank ?? 'nah'); // Output: "Blank: "
echo 'Zero: ' . ($zero ?? 'nah'); // Output: "Zero: 0"
echo 'False: ' . ($false ?? 'nah'); // Output: "False: "
```

If you are certain the variable/key exists but don't want to get a falsy value, you can use `?:` multiple times in a row:

```php
echo ('' ?: 0 ?: false ?: [] ?: 'default'); // Output: "default"
```